# Effective way to store and retrieve documents in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android application where there is a Store  which adds products. 
I save the products under the store unique ID.
e.g.:target:{Apples,iphone,powerbank}
flipkart:{flour,macbook,charger}
Now when I want to see what target sells I could use RecyclerView and show what target sells. Same for Flipkart.
but these products fall into different categories.So if I want my RecyclerView only to show Fruits I'll have to go through each document.
I had thought a way to solve this problem by Storing the product ids in each category but I believe it will take a lot of time to get each product.
Any suggestion on a structure I could use?
sorry for being so descriptive.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of tables you got in firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize your data and store in firestore.

lots of ways t do this. take this example, define a product, assign an id and categories to it / create a category branch and then add the product id into it and then find out what each id belong to.
now your shop will have just list of product id and you goto product branch to get all the information of the product for your view.

Comment: yes that is what I thought. But I figured it would perform bad

Comment: if you think performance is more important then you would have to go all the way on no-sql life. you dont use a join. you query for an object and it contains all the information you need. This will be super fast but you will be storing the data in multiple places.

Comment: if this is also not acceptable, firestore offers a datatype called "reference". this can be used to refer to another object in same branch or in different branch. have you tried this?

Comment: I think reference would be a good approach. Need to figure how to do it.

Comment: its pretty simple actually, if you are interested in reference.

Comment: instead of storing a value, use the path to the colletion : projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/[DATABASE_ID]/documents/[DOCUMENT_PATH].

Answer (score 0):

firestore supports [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and you can use them for specifying which documents you want to retrieve from a collection or collection group. If you want to normalize the data depends on the application. You can add a string list called categories and then use a query to retrieve documents that are in a specific category. I personally used this in many apps and it is very helpful. I hope this helps and don't forget to check the docs.